# how to change Dictionary's value when enumerate it?

Tags: c#

how to change Dictionary's value when enumerate it? 
the following code doesn't work, because we can not change dictionary's value when enumerating it. Is there any way to get around it? Or NO WAY? Thanks

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in mydictionary)
        {
            if (otherdictionary.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
            {
                mydictionary[kvp.Key] = otherdictionary[kvp.Key];

            }
            else
            {
                otherdictionary[kvp.Key] = mydictionary[kvp.Key];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please, reformat code, it's unredable now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a copy of the values you need to enumerate over before you enumerate over them, then you can change the original source.

Since you don't actually use the value, you can change the code to this:

```
foreach (string key in mydictionary.Keys.ToArray())
    if (otherdictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        mydictionary[key] = otherdictionary[key];
    else
        otherdictionary[key] = mydictionary[key];
```

Note the use of `.ToArray()` there to make a temporary array copy of the key collection. This is now separate from the source dictionary, so you can change the dictionary all you want.

Comment: @Lasse: Will the enumerator yield then? (yes, I'm new to this)

Comment: @Johann, sorry, I don't understand that question. You can enumerate over an array just as easily as a dictionary. What do you mean by "yield"?

Comment: Also, see Jon's answer for a more optimal solution.

Comment: @Lasse: I meant this: will the enumerator that is implemented by the returned array from ToArray() use "yield" so that ToArray() doesn't return a new array at every iteration?

Comment: `.ToArray()` will produce one array, `.GetEnumerator()` will return a new object implementing `IEnumerator<string>` and this object will internally keep a reference to the array originally produced, so no, there will not be produced a new array for each iteration here. The optimal thing I was commenting on was that if you used the `KeyValuePair` type, you could avoid additional lookups to extract the value out of the dictionary, look at Jons answer, he did it right.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way would be to take a copy first. As you only want the key value pairs, you might as well put them in a list rather than building a new dictionary though. Also, you can avoid doing quite as many lookups using `TryGetValue`.

```
var copy = myDictionary.ToList();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in copy)
{
    int otherValue;
    if (otherdictionary.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out otherValue))
    {
        mydictionary[kvp.Key] = otherValue;
    }
    else
    {
        otherdictionary[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another option, copy the keys collection to an array and use it in for each loop -

string[] arr1 = new string[mydictionary.Count];

mydictionary.Keys.CopyTo(arr1,0);

```
    foreach (string j in arr1)
    {
        if (otherdictionary.ContainsKey(j))
        {
            mydictionary[j] = otherdictionary[j];

        }
        else
        {
            otherdictionary[j] = mydictionary[j];
        } 
    }
```